# Why do i get 'undefined' at my request in Node and Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, crud

I'm creating my first API, I've used `.env` for database variables in this url:

```
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${mongo_user}:${mongo_pwd}@cluster0.ynvbj.mongodb.net/${mongo_db}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
```

then created the client:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
```

Then, a main function that calls the functions that finds data from Mongo like users:

```
async function main() {
      try {
             await client.connect();
             await  getUser(client, 'users', mongo_db);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        } finally {
            await client.close();
        }
}
    
main().catch(console.err);

//------GET
//user by Dni
async function getUser(client, coll, mongo_db){
      const collection = await client.db(`${mongo_db}`).collection(`${coll}`)
      .find({dni: 38383838}).toArray(function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);
            return results;
         })
   };
```

And finally, I created the routes, but I get `undefined`. I've check everything and I don't get what's wrong.

```
    const {getUser, getOrder, getProducts} = require('./db_connection')
    const {Router} = require('express')
    const router = Router()
   
    //GET
    //get user
    router.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
       let data = await getUser;
       res.json({data});
    })

module.exports = router;
```

And this is app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
require('dotenv').config();

//settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

//middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(express.json())

//server
 app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=> {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${app.get('port')}`)
})

//require api
app.use('/api', require('./api_routes'))
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code as code and not as images.

Comment: Hi, can you provide your code as code instead of images.
Also, can you provide a stack trace and the line that's giving you "undefined" please

Comment: @Dominik  Hi, i edited the question with the code, thank you.
This is in the terminal and I can't see the json data in localhost 

Server running on port 3002
undefined

Comment: @TheBritishAreComing Sure, i've edited so you can see the code. 
The terminal shows:
Server running on port 3002 
undefined

Comment: The line `let data = await getUser;` doesn't execute the function nor does it pass arguments that your are expecting. It needs to be `let data = await getUser(client, coll, mongo_db);`

Comment: @Dominik  I thought about that too but it still gets undefined. I'm still trying though

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your results are undefined, that could be for a lot of different reasons.

Where you have `console.log(results)` can you replace that with `console.debug(err, results);`

That might give you more insight into the reason it's not getting the results.

```
async function getUser(client, coll, mongo_db){
      const collection = await client.db(`${mongo_db}`).collection(`${coll}`)
      .find({dni: 38383838})
      .toArray(function(err, results) {
            console.debug(err, results);
            return results;
         })
   };
```

Comment: Omg this is what i got: MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended.

I think it might be the version of Mongo ! i'll try by upgrading it.